# Django - CSRF verification failed - after successfully logged in

Tags: python, django

I am getting CSRF verification failed when i return to back go back after login using django method.

It returns the sign in page even after i successfully log in. And it posts the error as CSRF verification failed.

Could I use to set anything in Django setting?

Comment: Not without seeing some code.

Comment: Can you show your form html, I fear something is wrong with your {% csrf_token %}

Comment: had you found solutions:

Answer (score 0):

Add to your form    `{% csrf_token %}`
Like this

```
<form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %} 
 <form>
```

Comment: He probably has it already since he says the problem is there when he goes back

Comment: Maybe you used  render_to_response , change to render(request, "index.html",)

Answer (score 0):

The CSRF token is rotated after the user logs in. If the user goes back in their browser after logging in and submits a form with the old token, then you will get a CSRF error.

If you refresh the page with the form after logging in, then the page will be reloaded with the new token, and CSRF verification should pass.